# Add additional field to response in pytest-django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-unittest, pytest-django

I'm new to testing and I spent a day finding a solution for my problem but I couldn't find any.
this is my serializer

**serilaizer.py**

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['user']

        return Lead.objects.create(organizer=user.organizeruser, **validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'agent', 'category', 'description', 'date_added',
                  'phone_number', 'email', 'converted_date'
                  ]
```

I have two types of users, organizer, and agent. organizer can create a lead but agent can't. and as you see I don't have organizer field. authenticated user will be added to the organizer field when a Lead is created.

**test.py**

```
    def test_if_lead_exist_return_200(self, api_client, leads_factory, user_factory):
        user = user_factory.create(is_organizer=True)
        api_client.force_authenticate(user=User(is_staff=True))

        lead = leads_factory.create()

        serializer = LeadSerializer(context={'request': user})
        print(serializer)
        # here I can see the user

        response = api_client.get(f'/api/leads/{lead.id}/', )

        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK

        assert response.data == {
            'id': lead.id,
            'first_name': lead.first_name,
            'last_name': lead.last_name,
            'age': lead.age,
            'organizer': lead.organizer.id,
            'agent': lead.agent.id,
            'category': lead.category.id,
            'description': lead.description,
            'date_added': lead.date_added,
            'phone_number': lead.phone_number,
            'email': lead.email,
            'converted_date': lead.converted_date,

        }
```

because there is no organizer field in the serialzier test won't pass and this is the result of the test

[image]

what can I do here? can I pass the organizer user to the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `organizer` into the fields.

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        # here I added the `organizer` field
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'agent', 'category', 'description', 'date_added', 'phone_number', 'email', 'converted_date', 'organizer']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
```

Comment: I removed the organizer field coz I didn't want the organizer user to see this field. anyway, I added it again and made it read-only and problem solved. thank you